# Firebase childAdded observer not fired when child pushed from firebase admin (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, firebase, swift3, firebase-admin

So I've been struggling to get this to work. Essentially I'm building a chat app and relying on an childAdded observer to check for new messages. In my iOS App I'm using the following:

```
//Get ref to users chat node
let messagesRef = dbRef.child("chats").child(self.userId)
//Only get most recent message

let messageQuery = messagesRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "messageTimeStamp").queryLimited(toLast: 1)

// Listen for new messages (last 1) being written to the Firebase DB
messageQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in...
```

This works fine when the user adds a message to /chat/uid. But when I add a child node from firebase admin (node js) the observer is never fired.

This is how I'm adding a message from the server side:

```
ref.child('chats/'+ uid).push(message);
```

The message is properly added to the tree, but no observer is ever fired.

Try as I might, and after a dozen tweaks that produced no difference, I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it just after posting the question...typical! Adding .set seems to make the observer work, even though the documentation states it's identical.

This works:

```
ref.child('chats/'+ uid).push().set(message);
```